# form not displayed in page source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am creating a veiw page in my rails application
this is my view page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "$.multiselect2side", :media => "all" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "$.multiselect2side" %>

        <script>
            $().ready(function() {
                $("#student_name_id").multiselect2side();
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            function callGrade(grade_value_123) {
                var id = grade_value_123;

            }
        </script>>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1> <%= @message%> </h1>
            <%= select(:grade,:id,@distinct_grade_list,{},:onchange => "callGrade(this.value)")%>
            <%= select(:period,:id,@distinct_period_list)%>
            <%= select(:student_name,:id,@student_name_list,{},{ :multiple => true, :size => 4 }) %>
            <br/>

            <%= radio_button_tag(:age, :child,{},:onclick => "callMe(this.id)") %><%= label_tag(:age_child, :" General Curriculum") %>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:age, :adult) %><%= label_tag(:age_adult, :"Common Core Standards") %>

            <br/>
            <div id="farzi" style="border: 3px solid red;margin-top: 20px">
                <% form_tag('call_ajax', :method=>'post', :multipart => true) do %>
                <p>
                    Subject:
                    <br />
                    <%= text_field_tag "subject" %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Priority:
                    <br />
                    <%= select_tag("priority", options_for_select([['Critical', '1'],
                    ['Important', '2'],['Standard','3']], '3')) %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Describe your problem:
                    <br />
                    <%= text_area_tag "description", "", :size=>"50x20" %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Add an attachment:
                    <br />
                    <%= file_field_tag "attachment" %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
                </p>
                <% end %>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

now when i execute the page , the page doent display any form ,

and when i check the page source , there is no form content inside the div with id= farzi

in the page source from browser it shows

```
 <div id="farzi" style="border: 3px solid red;margin-top: 20px">
            </div>
```

any explanation ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<% form_tag('call_ajax', :method=>'post', :multipart => true) do %>
```

with this

```
<%= form_tag('call_ajax', :method=>'post', :multipart => true) do %>
```

The `<%=` is used to output data from ruby in html.erb. If you just execute first command, it will return the correct data, but it won't output anything in html.